# Relationship between CDF and MGF?

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function

Suppose

- $X$ is a random variable $\in (0,1]$
- $f(x)$ is the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of this random variable
- $g(t)=\operatorname{mgf}(-t)$ where "mgf" is the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Can we infer the behavior of $g(t)$ at $t=t_0$ from behavior of $f(x)$ for $x\approx 2/t_0$?

Theorem 2.3 in Coqueret's "Approximation of probabilistic Laplace Transforms and their inverses" [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20180722184403id_/https://msp.org/camcos/2012/7-2/camcos-v7-n2-s.pdf#page=100) gives us the following characterization for $t_0\approx \infty$:

- $g(t)\sim t^{-k}$ for $t\approx \infty$, implies that $f(x)\sim x^k$ for $x\approx 0$

More precisely:

[image]

It appears the simpler relation holds for other values of $t$:

- behavior of $g(t)$ at $t=t_0$ depends on behavior of $f(x)$ for $x\approx \frac{2}{t_0}$.

Can this be made rigorous with some extra assumptions? (might need [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of $X$ to be bounded from below by $\epsilon>0$)

Here's a a toy $f$, $g$ where the above appears to hold:

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mgf-from-cdf.nb)

Motivation: neural network training loss over time $f(t)$ appears piecewise linear on log-log plot (Figure 1 of "broken neural scaling laws" [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.14891.pdf)). I want to model $f(t)$ as a mixture of exponentials with random scale $X$ and get a testable hypothesis on the shape of its CDF

Comment: $s \to 0$ means the survival function? Which relationship in behaviour are you referring to?

Comment: Your second paragraph is not very clear. *"cdf $\sim x^k$ for $t\in (b^{-1} x_0, b x_0)$"* This is the behaviour for 1-CDF? And how does the range for $t$ relate to the CDF, shouldn't it be a range for $x$ instead of $t$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus edited the question for clarity, let me know if it's not clear

Comment: What are "$x_{\min}$" and "$x_{\max}$"?  If they refer to limits of the support of $f,$ then trivially the answer is yes, because $f$ and $g$ determine each other.  Thus I am supposing you intend some other meaning.

Comment: That's a surprise, because I don't see anything about piecewise linearity in the question!  It's also a surprise insofar as the mgf encodes almost all information about the distribution in its germ at $0,$ which means that its more global behavior in any interval is practically irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber sorry, I meant "piecewise linear on log-log plot", it's under "Motivation". I don't understand how "encodes almost all the information at 0" is consistent with what I'm seeing on random variable whose CDF is $x$ for $x<x_0$ and $x^2$ for $x>x_0$

Comment: @whuber ok, I can see how mgf at 0 determines the rest, however in practice we have limited precision + noise so derivatives are too noisy to be useful. My setting is that I have values of MGF evaluated at points $-1,-2,-3,\ldots,-k$, which [appears to be piecewise linear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oO03.png) on log-log plot, and I'm interested in characterizing the shape of the CDF, which I suspect is similarly piecewise linear on log-log plot

Comment: Evidently you don't actually have an mgf: you have some kind of estimate from data.  This looks like an XY problem.  It would be good to know what the real situation is.  Is that explained in the final "motivation" section?  What's the basis for a mixture of exponentials model?  (Those are very difficult to fit!)

Comment: @whuber in the question I have an example where I have exact MGF and CDF, and the behavior of MGF at time $t$ relates to behavior of CDF at point $1/(2x)$. The relationship is the same as the one specified by Tauberian theorem (Theorem 2.3 in question) for $x\to 0$ but seems to extend to $x$ much larger than 0. So the question is whether this generalization extends beyond this toy example, or has been talked about in the literature

Comment: @whuber The basis for mixture of exponentials is that neural network training is a form of gradient descent, high-dimensional gradient descent is a mixture of exponentials because losses across dimensions contribute independently and each per-dimension loss goes down exponentially with its own scale